# ASP.NET cache in a console app?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, syscache

I have a console command line app that use NHibernate . I am trying to use second level caching . Is it possible to use NHibernate SysCache or SysCache2 , which have dependency on ASP.Net cache ( System.Web.Caching.Cache ) ?
Do I need IIS to use ASP.net cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it outside of ASP.net.

[NHibernate which cache to use for WinForms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068019/nhibernate-which-cache-to-use-for-winforms-application)

and

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheASPNETCacheOutsideOfASPNET.aspx